# Pass argument into telnet in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, telnet

How do you pass arguments in telnet using bash. When I tried to push I keep getting an error.

Input

```
echo "status" | telnet localhost 5555 > /tmp/text.txt
```

Output

```
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

I was expecting the output to redirected to a file for parsing however I am recieving an error.

Comment: You may want to use `nc` instead of `telnet`.

Comment: What you are seeing was written to stderr. I don't see any indication of an error

Comment: Please edit your question to show if there Is some message in the file `/tmp/text.txt`. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Telnet can't do what you are trying to do.  See full explanation in this [**posting**](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/160595/how-to-redirect-stdout-stdin-to-telnet).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the response. I was able to get the output however I had to add quit directive to get out of nc from bash. Here is my statement

```
echo "status" | nc -w 2 localhost 5555 > /tmp/test.txt
```